# NGINX cannot find static files when serving multiple applications

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I have an application running on port 3000 and another on 3001. I cannot seem to resolve any static files for the application on 3001 however. My current NGINX configuration is:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  my_server_name;

    ssl_certificate "my_cert";
    ssl_certificate_key "my_key";

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /contact-us/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
    }
}
```

Here is my express app.js running on 3001:

```
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , async = require('async');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'pug');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

function init() {
  app.get('/', routes.index);
  app.get('/join', routes.join);
  app.get('/survey', routes.survey);
  app.post('/surveySubmit', routes.surveySubmit);
  http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
  });
}

init();
```

And finally here are the assets/script tags:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(name="viewport",content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    title= title 
    link(rel="icon",href="images/icons/favicon.ico")

    link(rel="stylesheet",type="text/css",href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/
bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" ,crossorigin="anonymous")

    link(type="text/css",href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserr
at:wght@400;600&display=swap")

    link(href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")
    link(href="fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css")
    link(href="vendor/animate/animate.css")
    link(href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css")
    link(href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css")
    link(href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css")
    link(href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css")
    link(href='css/main.css')
    link(type="/text/css", href='css/util.css')

script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",crossorigin="anonymous")

    script(type='application/javascript', src='vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js')

    script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js", crossorigin="anonymous")

    script(src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js", crossorigin="anonymous")

    script(type='application/javascript', src='vendor/select2/select2.min.js')
    script(type='application/javascript', src='vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js')
    script(type='application/javascript', src='vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js')

  body
    block content
```

I am currently getting 404s on all of the assets and unable to manually modify the URL to the correct path either.

Some things I've tried:

1. Modifying the root URL in the nginx config,
2. Changing the script tagurl to relative/absolute/etc.
3. Messing with try_files directives.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know much about express but shouldn't you change all your paths to be absolute with a leading `/`, or is that a configuration of the framework. You are using nested paths that are relative, which is definitely not what should be there. i.e. `/vendor/select2/select2.min.css`

Comment: I mentioned in the bulletpoints at the bottom that i tried absolute paths. With absolute paths it catches the / location and sends the request to localhost:3000 instead. Extra config may be required, im not sure